# Count the number of times object an property exists in mongo array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document structure like this

```
[{
 name: "Something",
 codes: [
         {type: 11}, 
         {type: 11}, 
         {type: 15}
        ]
 },
 {
 name: "Another",
 codes: [
         {type: 11}, 
         {type: 12}, 
         {type: 15},
         {type: 11}
        ]
 }]]
```

I need to count how many times `type = 11` appears per entry, in the collection. 
I have am stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though a `$match` to filter out only the documents containing the codes of a particular type can be applied, it should not be applied to this particular problem statement. Since it would filter out the documents that do not have the particular type code, from the output.

You need to:

- `Unwind` each document based on the codes field.
- If codes field is of the required type, `project` a field `wantedType` with value `1`
  or else with value `0`.
- `Group` by the `_id` field to get the sum of `wantedType` field, which
  gives you number of the wanted type codes in the particular document.
- So even if a document does not have the wanted type code, it will be presented in the output with 
  `0` as its count.

Code:

```
var typeCountToCalculate = 11;

db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$codes"},
{$project:{"name":1,
          "wantedType":{$cond:[{$eq:["$codes.type",typeCountToCalculate ]},1,0]}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "name":{$first:"$name"},"count":{$sum:"$wantedType"}}}
])
```

o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54ad79dae024832588b287f4"),
        "name" : "Another",
        "count" : 2
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54ad79dae024832588b287f3"),
        "name" : "Something",
        "count" : 2
}
```

Comment: @EdgarMartinez Until you realize it is completeltly wrong an not very informative for people learning. This was a bad accept.

Answer (score 6):

The aggregation framework of MongoDB is the answer here. The key operations are [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) for processing the array contents into "normalized" documents and the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage for obtaining the counts.

There is also optimization happening with the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stages. Both at the beginning of the query in order to filter out documents that cannot possibly match and after the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage, in order to remove those elements ( now documents ) that certainly do not match the conditions:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match to filter documents
    { "$match": { "codes.type": 11 }},

    // Unwind to 'de-normalize'
    { "$unwind": "$codes" },

    // Match to filter again, but remove the array elements
    { "$match": { "codes.type": 11 }},

    // Count the occurrences of the the matches
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$codes.type",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Naturally, if you pulled out all of the "matching" then you get the "count" per "type" over the whole collection.

In modern versions you can alter this a bit with the [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator as of MongoDB 2.6 and greater. If a little contrived due to the recursive nature of this pipeline stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match to filter documents
    { "$match": { "codes.type": 11 }},

    // Filter out non matches
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ 
                { "$ifNull": [ "$type", 11 ] },
                11
            ]},
            "then": "$$DESCEND",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}

    // Unwind to 'de-normalize'
    { "$unwind": "$codes" },

    // Count the occurrences of the the matches
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$codes.type",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
)
```

It's a different way of filtering, and perfectly valid if your server supports it. Just be careful if using in other examples with nested levels.

**Always** filter for the matching values you want to work on **"first"** before doing any other operations. This removes un-necessary work from being processed in the aggregation pipeline. No use processing 100,000 documents if only 10,000 are possible matches and only 2,000 elements within those documents match as well.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$codes"},
{$match : { 'codes.type' : 11}} ,
{$group : { 
    _id : { 'name': '$name', 'type' : '$codes.type'}
    ,count: { $sum: 1 }
}},
]).result
```

output will be:

```
{
    "0" : {
        "_id" : {
            "name" : "Another",
            "type" : 11
        },
        "count" : 2
    },
    "1" : {
        "_id" : {
            "name" : "Something",
            "type" : 11
        },
        "count" : 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point including the match but what it does is , it will not match the documents which don't have the type=11 code. So in the output the,corresponding document count will not be included as 0.